# Introducing a change of variable to make Sigmoid function convex

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

I have an optimization problem with convex objective, but there is a Sigmoid function $s(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ in the constraint that makes it non-convex (optimization variable $x$ spans the whole real line). The non-convex constraint is of the form $s(x)\le a$ where $a$ is a given constant. I am trying to introduce a change of variable like $x = f(y)$ that makes the constraint convex. The new objective will not be convex (almost certainly) but that does not matter, we can introduce convex approximations for objective later. My question is

Can we introduce a change of variable like $x = f(y)$ that turns the constraint $s(x)\le a$ into a convex constraint in terms of $y$ where $a$ is a given constant and $s(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ is the standard Sigmoid function?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right, then defining $y$ such that,
$$x = \log\left(\frac{1}{y^2} - 1\right)$$ turns the constrains into $y^2<a$ and $y\mapsto y^2-a$ is convex.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution possible is actually the inverse function of the constraint, in other words the change of variables $y = \text{logit}(x) = \ln\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)$ where the 'logit' function is the inverse of Sigmoid which gives the simple linear constraint $y\le \text{logit}(a)$.